# Displaying a NumberPicker value to another activity's NumberPicker

Tags: java, android, android-intent, methods, numberpicker

The app contains two activities, `FirstScreen` and `SecondScreen`. The `FirstScreen` contains a NumberPicker `np1` and a button `toSecondScreen`. Pressing the button `toSecondScreen` will transfer the app to the activity `SecondScreen` which also contains a NumberPicker `np1sc`.

What Im trying to achieve is get the value selected from the NumberPicker `np1` of the `FirstScreen` and display it to the `SecondScreen`'s NumberPicker `np2`.

So far, the methods i've tried seems to be incorrectly used. Codes are given below with the corresponding error message.

```
FirstScreen.java

public class FirstScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button toSecondScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);

        final NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.NP1);
        np1.setMinValue(0);
        np1.setMaxValue(5);
        np1.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
        localBundle.putInt("NumPicker2Val", Integer.valueOf(np1.getValue()));
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
        localIntent.putExtras(localBundle);


    toSecondScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondScreen.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

For the second activity,

```
    SecondScreen.java

public class SecondScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);

        final NumberPicker np1sc = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.NP1SC);
        np1sc.setMinValue(0);
        np1sc.setMaxValue(5);
        np1sc.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("NumPicker2Val");
        np1sc.setDisplayedValues(string1);
    }
}
```

Using the method `setDisplayedValues(string1)` gives me a message: `setDisplayedValues() in NumberPicker cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)` I somehow understood the error it gives out but I don't know how to correctly use the methods anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`setDisplayedValues()` method accepts string array (look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues(java.lang.String[])) for API), so you need to convert `string1` to string array and pass it as shown below:

```
np1sc.setDisplayedValues(new String[] {string1});//pass string array
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thanks for the info too :)

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to do. I think they're just trying to set the _selected_ value in the second `Activity`, not the display values.

Comment: Yes that's what im trying to do, but I'm somehow confused right now. What is the difference of setting the selected values, from displaying the selected values to the second activity's number picker?

Comment: I tried this method, `np1sc.setDisplayedValues(new String[] {string1}); ` but after pressing the button, the app keeps stopping and exiting with a logcat message `threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164ac80)
`

Comment: @AxlRosel In your Screen1 activity, you're converting the value to an int and put an int into the extras. In Screen2 you're trying to get the value as a string from the extras. That does not work. As you need the value as a string, change your screen1 to `localBundle.putString("NumPicker2Val", np1.getValue())`. Additionally, do NOT set that value in your onCreate method, as this will only get you the initial value, but move the creation of the Intent to the OnClickListener, so you get the actually selected value and can send it to the Screen2 activity.

Comment: @Ridcully I've tried your suggestion, changed the screen1 to `localBundle.putString("NumPicker1Val", String.valueOf(numberPicker1.getValue()));` and put the intent creation on the OnClickListener.  It looks like: 
`Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
                localBundle.putString("NumPicker1Val", String.valueOf(numberPicker1.getValue()));
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondScreen.class);
                myIntent.putExtras(localBundle);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);`

The app is still crashing and exiting.

Comment: Sorry, I just had a look at the documentation of NumberPicker. You were right by using the int value in screen1, but at screen2 you have to get that value from the extras again as an int value and use `np1sc.setValue(value)` to set the int value. Do not use the `setDisplayValues()` method.

Comment: @Ridcully it worked! Thanks! I followed what you said and used the method `setValue()`.